# If I delete all of the files in my Amazon s3 bucket will that clear cloudfront?

Tags: caching, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm serving all of my static content from Cloudfront via my S3 bucket.

If I delete everything in my S3 bucket, will that clear the CloudFront cache? Or, since I set cache-control to very far future, will CloudFront not even check to see whether anything is in S3?

Is there any easy way to clear the entire CloudFront cache? I just learned about caching and--without thinking--set ALL of the cache related headers to a year in the future. I know that I can change the file names in my HTML to get around this and I can also invalidate the files one by one, but I've got a large number of files at the moment and would love a simple way to do it across the board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to delete ALL the content from your CloudFront distribution the easiest way is to just disable, then delete the distribution completely, then start fresh with a new, empty distribution.

You can disable and delete an existing distribution using the AWS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

If you have a large distribution and only want to delete SOME of the objects, then the [Object Invalidation](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/08/new-cloudfront-feature-invalidation.html) mentioned by cloudberryman is your best bet.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You can create invalidation by clicking Distribution setting of your CloudFront.

Give OBJECT PATH /*

(It will flush the CloudFront)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force clear CloudFront cache you can use [Object Invalidation](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/08/new-cloudfront-feature-invalidation.html).